# Vim function inserting static text with passed argument

Tags: vim

## Background

I'm interested in writing a function that assigned to keyboard shortcut <kbd>;</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> when invoked would:

- Take user argument
- Compute value reflecting `80 - (string_length(argument) + 4) = n`
- Insert static text of content:

  ```
  # + space argument + space + n * "-"
  ```

### Example

For the argument `abc` the function would insert:

```
# abc ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Problem

The code below does not insert the desired text but only inserts value `0`.

## Code

```
" The functions inserts RStudio like section break. Starting with a word and
" continuing with a number of - characters.


function! InsertSectionBreak()
    let title = input("Section title: ")            " Collect title
    let title_length = strlen(title)                " Number of repetitions
    let times = 80 - (title_length + 1)
    let char = "-"                                  " Create line break
    let sep_line =  repeat(char, times)     
    let final_string = '#' + title + ' ' + sep_line " Create final title string
    call setline('.', , getline('.'), final_string) " Get current line and insert string
endfunction


" Map function to keyboard shortcut ';s'
nmap <silent>  ;s  :call InsertSectionBreak()<CR>
```

---

## *Update*

Following advice expressed in comments, I've redrafted the function to:

```
function! InsertSectionBreak()
    let title = input("Section title: ")            " Collect title
    let title_length = strlen(title)                " Number of repetitions
    let times = 80 - (title_length + 1)
    let char = "-"                  " Create line break
    let sep_line =  repeat(char, times)     
    let final_string = '#' + title + ' ' + sep_line " Create final title string
    call append(line('.'), final_string)            " Get current line and insert string
endfunction
```

### *Behaviour*

The function now inserts **`0`** under current line. I reckon that the `final_string` is not constructed properly.

Comment: I tried `call setline('.', , getline('.'), final_string)`, but got `E116: Invalid arguments for function setline`.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for looking into this; what I'm trying to achieve is to insert text in the current line and to my limited understanding of VimL `setline('.', , getline('.'), ...)` is supposed to do that. Have nothing against a potential solution using `insert` or `append`.

Comment: Why the double comma? `'.', ,` is simply a syntax error as far as I can tell.

Comment: `setline` only has two arguments (your second and third arguments should just be deleted). Also, setline will replace the current line, which I can't imagine you want.

Comment: @ohlec OK, maybe append would be better....

Comment: I don't know why you're calling `getline()` at all, and like @melpomene said, the empty argument after that seems like a typo. With `append`, it would look something like `append(line('.'), final_string)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `setline` seems strange — firstly, you're passing too many (and wrong) arguments. Also, `setline` will replace the current line, which you say you don't want.

Something like

```
append(line('.'), final_string)
```

should work better.

Also, for concatenating strings, use the `.` operator rather than `+` (see [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/26.html), for example).

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. Your point on concatenating the strings provided the required fix: `let final_string = '#' .  '  ' . title . '  ' . sep_line`