# VIM command to insert multiline text with argument

Tags: python, function, vim

new VIM user. I'm trying to make creating python properties easier for my class definitions. What I would like for say I type

`:pyp x`

then VIM will autofill where my cursor is

```
@property
def x(self):
   return self.x
@property.setter
   def x(self,val):
      self._x = val
```

or more abstractly I type

`:pyp <property_name>`

and VIM fills

```
@property
def <property_name>(self):
   return self.<property_name>
@property.setter
   def <property_name>(self,val):
      self._<property_name> = val
```

I've looked at a few posts and the wikis on functions, macros but I'm very unsure of how to go about it or what to even look up as I am brand new VIM user, less than a week old.

I tried using [this][1] as an example, in my .vimrc but I couldn't even get that to work.

Edit:

So the code I am currently trying is

```
function! PythonProperty(prop_name)
 let cur_line = line('.')
 let num_spaces = indent('.')
 let spaces = repeat(' ',num_spaces)
 let lines = [ spaces."@property",
             \ spaces."def ".prop_name."(self):",
             \ spaces."   return self.".property,
             \ spaces."@property.setter",
             \ spaces."def".prop_name."(self,val)",
             \ spaces."   self._".prop_name." = val" ]
 call append(cur_line,lines)
endfunction

and I am getting the errors
```

E121: Undefined variable: prop_name

```
I am typing
`:call PythonProperty("x")`

  [1]: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9644/how-to-use-a-variable-in-the-expression-of-a-normal-command
```

Comment: there are plugins for code generation from some template.  like snippet, neosnippet...   you can define the template

Comment: @Kent Yeah, the system I am working on, its very very difficult if not impossible to get pluggins so I have to do stuff through my vimrc or other method. Basically trying to get a plugin installed could take half a year.

Comment: you could ask it in [vim exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MathWannaBe456 you can install vim plugins in your home directory, it is user-specific stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a vim function to insert a block of static text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690386/writing-a-vim-function-to-insert-a-block-of-static-text)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+insert+text+argument

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52254413/7976758

Comment: @Kent we don't have internet on this particular system. it is completely locked down and nothing can be installed anywhere without admin priv

Comment: @MathWannaBe456 you cant clone a git repo to a USB on another system and copy it over?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble No we aren't allowed storage devices in the building

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> E121: Undefined variable: prop_name

In VimScript variables have scopes. The scope for function arguments is `a:`, while the default inside a function is `l:` (local variable). So the error means that `l:prop_name` was not yet defined.

Now how I do this:

```
function! s:insert_pyp(property)
    let l:indent = repeat(' ', indent('.'))
    let l:text = [
        \ '@property',
        \ 'def <TMPL>(self):',
        \ '    return self.<TMPL>',
        \ '@property.setter',
        \ '    def <TMPL>(self,val):',
        \ '        self._<TMPL> = val'
    \ ]
    call map(l:text, {k, v -> l:indent . substitute(v, '\C<TMPL>', a:property, 'g')})
    call append('.', l:text)
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 Pyp :call <SID>insert_pyp(<q-args>)
```

Alternatively, we can simulate actual key presses (note that we don't need to put indents in the template anymore; hopefully, the current buffer has `set ft=python`):

```
function! s:insert_pyp2(property)
    let l:text = [
        \ '@property',
        \ 'def <TMPL>(self):',
        \ 'return self.<TMPL>',
        \ '@property.setter',
        \ 'def <TMPL>(self,val):',
        \ 'self._<TMPL> = val'
    \ ]
    execute "normal! o" . substitute(join(l:text, "\n"), '\C<TMPL>', a:property, 'g') . "\<Esc>"
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 Pyp2 :call <SID>insert_pyp2(<q-args>)
```

> its very very difficult if not impossible to get pluggins

I suggest you to watch this [video](https://youtu.be/XA2WjJbmmoM?t=2304) on youtube. In fact, many of Vim plugins are just overkill.

Comment: I'm getting error
`E121 Undefined variable: k`
It does however spit out the template though

Comment: @MathWannaBe456 Not sure why so, I have none. Maybe buggy Vim version? Try old syntax for `map()` (without lambda), or even plain `for i in range(len(l:text))`.

Comment: Yeah im totally confused on why it isnt working. I read up on the map with lambda, key-val thing and it seems like it should be working

Comment: Is this how you would do it with the for loop?

`for i in range(len(l:text))`
`l:text[i] = l:indent . substitute(l:text[i], '\C<TMPL>', a:property, 'g')`
`endfor`

Comment: @MathWannaBe456 Yes, except you forgot 'let'.