# How do I add a vim command generating a class source and header files for C++?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, vim

When I type `:Class Toto` from **VIM command line**, I want to get the header and the source file with their templates like what any editor do when we create a new class. So if

**Input** 
`:Class Toto`

then

**Output**:

> toto.h

```
#ifndef TOTO_H
#define TOTO_H

class toto
{
    public:
        toto();
        virtual ~toto();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // TOTO_H
```

> toto.cpp

```
#include "toto.h"

toto::toto()
{
    //ctor
}


toto::~toto()
{
    //dtor
}
```

I get:

`./src/toto.c`

`./include/toto.h`

generated automatically (with `src` and `include` folders  will be perfect)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57074531/vim-command-to-insert-multiline-text-with-argument Basically, you need only to add a couple of Ex commands to create/write files/buffers.

Comment: Also you could look at creating and using templates with `vim` https://shapeshed.com/vim-templates/#using-templates-in-vim

Comment: UltiSnip plugin is the bazooka for templates (here called snippets): https://github.com/vim-scripts/UltiSnips

Answer (score 7, accepted):

below a function, i added to my `~/.vimrc` file

```
 "C++ Class Generator                                                                                                    
 function! Class(ClassName)                                                                                              
    "==================  editing header file =====================                                                       
     let header = a:ClassName.".h"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     :vsp %:h/.h                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
     call append(0,"#ifndef ".toupper(a:ClassName)."_H")                                                                 
     call append(1,"#define ".toupper(a:ClassName)."_H")                                                           
     call append(2," ")                                                                                                  
     call append(3,"class ".a:ClassName )                                                                                
     call append(4, "{")                                                                                                 
     call append(5, "   public:")                                                                                        
     call append(6, "      ".a:ClassName."();")                                                                          
     call append(7, "      virtual ~".a:ClassName."();")                                                                 
     call append(8, "   protected:")                                                                                     
     call append(9, "   private:")                                                                                       
     call append(10, "};")                                                                                               
     call append(11,"#endif // ".toupper(a:ClassName)."_H")                                                              
     :execute 'write' header                                                                                             
   "================== editing source file ========================                                                      
     let src    = a:ClassName.".cpp"                                                                                     
     :vsp %:h/.cpp                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
     call append(0,"#include ".a:ClassName.".h")                                                                          
     call append(1," ")                                                                                                   
     call append(2,a:ClassName."::".a:ClassName."()")                                                                           
     call append(3,"{")                                                                                                   
     call append(4,"//ctor ")                                                                                             
     call append(5,"}")                                                                                                   
     call append(6," ")                                                                                                   
     call append(7," ")                                                                                                   
     call append(8,a:ClassName."::~".a:ClassName."()")                                                                         
     call append(9,"{")                                                                                                   
     call append(10,"//dtor ")                                                                                            
     call append(11,"}")                                                                                                  
     :execute 'write' src
endfunction
```

> open **vim** and type `:call Class("toto")`

your vim will be splited to 3 parts:

1. you current file
2. toto.h
3. toto.cpp
   with the templates mentioned above

> if you want to cutomize the command `:call Class("toto")` to `:Class toto` 
>   add this line in your `~/.vimrc` :

```
command! -nargs=1 Class call Class(<f-args>)
```

**result :**

[image]

Comment: I found this to be a really good approach, so i upvoted it. i also proposed a variation i did as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight variation of the work of Saif Faidi.

The only thing it brings:

- Starting in insert mode in the desired spot.
- Not using line numbers. So that insertions can be relative to where the
  cursor is. In my case When creating a file with the extension .hpp or
  .cpp, some automatic headers and inclusion protections are inserted.
  Then those lines take effect:

```
    "C++ CLASS GENERATOR: OPENING 2 NEW FILES
function! ClassNew(ClassName)
    "==================  editing source file =================================
    execute "vsp %:h/" . a:ClassName . ".class.cpp"
    "At this stage the autocomands for this filetype are done.
    "   example: inserting the header, and the ifndef... Then:
    :execute "normal! a#include \"" . a:ClassName . ".class.hpp\"\<cr>\<cr>"
    :execute "normal! a" . a:ClassName . "::" . a:ClassName ."(void)\<cr>{\<cr>"
    :execute "normal! a\<tab>return ;\<cr>"
    :execute "normal! a}\<cr>\<cr>"
    :execute "normal! a" . a:ClassName . "::~" . a:ClassName ."(void)\<cr>{\<cr>"
    :execute "normal! a\<tab>return ;\<cr>"
    :execute "normal! a}"
    "Comment this line if you dont want to save files straight away.
    ":execute 'write'

    "==================  editing header file =================================
    execute "vsp %:h/" . a:ClassName . ".class.hpp"
    "At this stage the autocomands for this filetype are done.
    "   example: inserting the header, and the ifndef... Then:
    :execute "normal! a" . "class " . a:ClassName ."\<cr>{\<cr>"
    :execute "normal! a\<tab>public:\<cr>"
    :execute "normal! a\<tab>\<tab>" . a:ClassName . "(void);\<cr>"
    :execute "normal! a\<tab>\<tab>~" . a:ClassName . "(void);\<cr>\<cr>"
    :execute "normal! a\<tab>protected:\<cr>\<cr>"
    :execute "normal! a\<tab>private:\<cr>\<cr>"
    :execute "normal! a};"
    :execute "normal! ka\<tab>\<tab>"
    "Comment out this line if you dont want to start in insert mode
    :startinsert!
    "Comment this line if you dont want to save files straight away.
    :execute 'write'
endfunction
```